# Primefaces 4 fileUpload handler not called

Tags: java, spring, primefaces, jsf-2.2

First of all, I have to say, that I've read all (at least a lot :)) questions here and on primefaces forums about fileuploader issues.

My configuration:

**Primefaces 4**

**JSF 2.2**

**Spring**

**Apache Tomcat 7**

**Maven**

I am converting a richfaces project to primefaces, and I'm stuck with a fileUpload component that is not calling the handler method.

I have tried (altough I know that from Primefaces 4 it is not necessary) putting filters in the web.xml. I've also tried without filters. I have spring security filters and a language filter among some others, but the PF was first. I've also tried setting the dispatcher to FORWARD.

I have all the needed dependecies in Maven (commons - I know that from version 4 it is not required, but nevertheless I tried)

**The xhtml part:**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        ... /* not relevant code here */ ...

                            <p:graphicImage value="#{systemParamsController.image}"
                                id="logo" />

                            <p:fileUpload
                                fileUploadListener="#{systemParamsController.listener}"
                                fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                                uploadLabel="#{msg['button.upload.jpg']}"
                                cancelLabel="#{msg['button.cancel']}"
                                invalidFileMessage="alert('#{msg['upload.invalidtype']}');"
                                update="logo" mode="advanced">
                            </p:fileUpload>
                            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.save']}" onclick="this.disabled=true"  oncomplete="this.disabled=false"
                        action="#{systemParamsController.save}" styleClass="qs-button"
                        ajax="false" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </center>
    </h:form>
```

**The backing bean:**

```
public synchronized void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
  logger.debug("uploadListener!");
  UploadedFile item = event.getFile();
  getModel().getCustomer().setLogo(imageResizer.doResize(item.getContents(), 30, Side.HEIGHT));
}
```

If I click on choose, I can select a file, but after that nothing happens. The handler is not called, because there is no log message, the upload file button is inactive. I have used this component before for more complex issues without problem, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Open you favorite Javascript console...is it giving any meaningful error? What is the scope of you backing bean?

Comment: :) Cant express my thanks enough for the js console hint...There was a syntax error in the substituted text in the invalidFileMessage...
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter as the first filter in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you're having trouble with the default primefaces uploader you can try the commons fileupload:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

We're using this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, try putting the file upload in its own form.